# Lightning Accordion Section Title Bold

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, lightning-design-system, slds, accordion

[image]Hello Lightning Experts,

My requirement is to bold the titles so I used `slds-page-header__title slds-truncate` in my `lightning:accordionSection` tag but the sub-headers is also getting bold. What do I need to do to display the bold headers and the normal sub-headers ? please take a look on my code and the Lightning UI. TIA

```
`<lightning:accordionSection class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" name="{!$Label.c.MEDICATIONS}" label="{!$Label.c.MEDICATIONS}">
                    <c:Assessment_Medications caseId="{! v.caseId}" 
                                              aura:id="medicationCmpId"
                                              draftMedicationList ="{! v.medicationList}"
                                              isAssessmentCompleted ="{! v.isStatusCompleted}"/>
                </lightning:accordionSection> `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case `slds-truncate` styles applicable to all inner components which you don't want,  so you need apply styles for 'slds-accordion__summary-heading only. below code works for me.

```
 .THIS .slds-accordion__summary-heading{
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Dandamudi. perfectly worked !

Comment: Note that this will not work if/when you migrate to LWC. In that case please see the link sfdcfox posted in his comment on the question.

Comment: oh okay , Ya I will  take a look on it. Thanks!